# IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 154 out of range, size 154

Tags: modeling

[image]
The unselected part is a normal model. Since I created the selected part myself, such errors have occurred in exporting the model. When I delete the selected part and export it again, it can be exported normally, so I think there is a problem with this part of the model I built myself, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\export_xnalara_model.py", line 68, 
in getOutputFilename xpsExport() File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\timing.py", line 31, 
in wrap ret = f(*args) File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\export_xnalara_model.py", line 114, 
in xpsExport xpsMeshes = exportMeshes(selectedArmature, selectedMeshes) File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\export_xnalara_model.py", line 178, 
in exportMeshes meshVerts, meshFaces = getXpsVertices(selectedArmature, mesh) File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\export_xnalara_model.py", line 425, 
in getXpsVertices boneId, boneWeight = getBoneWeights(mesh, vertex, armature) File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.3\scripts\addons\XNALaraMesh\export_xnalara_model.py", line 471, 
in getBoneWeights boneName = mesh.vertex_groups[groupIdx].name IndexError: bpy_prop_collection[index]: index 154 out of range, size 154
```

Comment: you should ask the creator of add-on XNALaraMesh for that error....

Comment: The unselected part is a normal model. Since I created the selected part myself, such errors have occurred in exporting the model. When I delete the selected part and export it again, it can be exported normally, so I think there is a problem with this part of the model I built myself, but I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: If you have added the selected part, the weights for the armature might be missing (keyword "weight painting"). The weights for the bones are stored in vertex groups and the error message mentions bones & vertex groups. For a quick test select the mesh, then the armature (should be highlighted in orange=parent) and do a Ctrl+P > *With Automatic Weights*. Blender then tries to calculate the weights for the whole mesh. Pay attention to the status bar. If there is a "heat weighting failed..." error message then the operation failed & there's something wrong with the mesh (duplicated verts, etc)